# How can I see a full log of exceptions in JAVA?

Tags: java, exception-logging

When I run some java program with a command **java ExceptionTest** , exceptions are sometimes omitted and looks like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aa/bb/DD
        at SOMEWHERE(unknown source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aaa.bbb.CC
        at SOMEWHER(unknown source)
        ... 13 more
```

I'd like to see 13 more exceptions in this case. Is there an option to see all exception log?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You already see them, it's only the ridiculous way Java (and Logback by defaul) prints exceptions by default. This stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aa/bb/DD
        at SOMEWHERE(unknown source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aaa.bbb.CC
        at SOMEWHER(unknown source)
        ... 13 more
```

actually means the following program flow (from bottom to top):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aaa.bbb.CC
        at SOMEWHER(unknown source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aa/bb/DD
        at SOMEWHERE(unknown source)
```

The `... 13 more` (`N common frames omitted` in Logback) only means that these exceptions were already printed before. In Logback you can restructure stack track to avoid duplicates and print stack lines always in correct order, see [my blog](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2011/09/logging-exceptions-root-cause-first.html).

Answer (score 9):

there aren't 13 more exceptions. There are 13 more lines to the call stack which are identical to previous call stacks, as described here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()